# Windows 10 recent update changed your user profile folder as well?

Tags: windows

I've experienced a very strange thing with the latest creators update for Windows 10. I had a user whos folder was called "bert". After the update I've received a new profile folder named "bert.SOME-RANDOM-STUFF". I was still able to log in with my original account, but it was completely empty. Anyone else experienced something similar? Why did this happen? I'm just curious.

This event BTW moved me to re-install Ubuntu on my laptop and make my games work on it. Luckily WINE was upgraded to a level where I can easily install almost any Windows app and use them when I need it, so byebye windows, hello linux again. :)

Comment: Voting to move it on SuperUser